# ValidationRule - validate on property update

Tags: wpf, validation, textblock

Greetings, 
how can I validate if value in TextBlock is ok?
I have a TextBox where I bind "Amount" property and a TextBlock which uses Multibinding: Price Property and Amount property. I would like to do something like that:
In case of changing Amount i would like to validate if the price is greater than xx (which is the constant).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have create validation rule class(derived from validation rule) for binding validation.
Here is some sample to how to implement binding validation in WPF

[Sample 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx)

[Sample 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i know how to create validation rules. 
I just want to fire validation in my **TextBlock** when the value in other control (**TextBox**) changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple flag in XAML that sets when to validate.

<'local:ValidationRules **ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"** />

Hope that helps.